Tensorflow: Input to reshape is a tensor with 1280 values, but the requested shape has 640 [Op:Reshape]
I am working on an RL agent for NES Tetris using tensorflow and tf-agents but I'm having trouble, due to a seeming bug in the defualt actornetwork I have to write a custom version from scratch in order to have 5 actions in the action_spec, unfortunately I'm having some trouble, everytime I run the code I'm getting an error.
Here is the code
import os
# Keep using keras-2 (tf-keras) rather than keras-3 (keras).
os.environ['TF_USE_LEGACY_KERAS'] = '1'

import socket
import json
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
from tf_agents.environments import PyEnvironment
from tf_agents.specs import array_spec
from tf_agents.networks.actor_distribution_network import ActorDistributionNetwork
from tf_agents.networks import network, value_network
from tf_agents.agents.ppo.ppo_agent import PPOAgent
from tf_agents.trajectories import trajectory
from tf_agents.replay_buffers import tf_uniform_replay_buffer
from tf_agents.utils import common
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts
tfd = tfp.distributions


class CustomActorDistributionNetwork(network.Network):
    def __init__(self, input_tensor_spec, output_tensor_spec, fc_layer_params=(100,), name='CustomActorDistributionNetwork'):
        super(CustomActorDistributionNetwork, self).__init__(input_tensor_spec, state_spec=(), name=name)

        self._output_tensor_spec = output_tensor_spec
        self._fc_layers = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_units, activation='relu') for num_units in fc_layer_params]
        # We need 2 logits per action for binary actions
        num_actions = np.prod(output_tensor_spec.shape)
        self._logits_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_actions * 2, activation=None)

    def call(self, observations, step_type=None, network_state=(), training=False):
        del step_type  # Unused.
        observations = tf.convert_to_tensor(observations)
        batch_size = tf.shape(observations)[0]

        for layer in self._fc_layers:
            observations = layer(observations, training=training)

        logits = self._logits_layer(observations, training=training)
        num_actions = np.prod(self._output_tensor_spec.shape)
        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 2])

        action_distribution = tfd.Independent(
            tfd.Categorical(logits=logits),
            reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)

        return action_distribution, network_state

class TetrisEnvironment(PyEnvironment):
    def __init__(self):
        self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(5,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='action')  # 5 buttons: down, left, right, A, B
        self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(204,), dtype=np.float32, minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0, name='observation')
        self._state = np.zeros(204, dtype=np.float32)
        self._episode_ended = False
        self._score = 0
        self._game_state = 0
        self._start_time = time.time()

    def action_spec(self):
        return self._action_spec

    def observation_spec(self):
        return self._observation_spec

    def _reset(self):
        self._state = np.zeros(204, dtype=np.float32)
        self._episode_ended = False
        self._score = 0
        self._game_state = 0
        self._start_time = time.time()
        return ts.restart(self._state)

    def _step(self, action):
        if self._episode_ended:
            return self.reset()


        # Calculate elapsed time
        elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
        log_time = np.log(max(elapsed_time, 1))  # Ensure log is defined (log(1) = 0)

        # Calculate reward
        reward = log_time ** self._score

        if self._game_state == 10:
            self._episode_ended = True

        if self._episode_ended:
            return ts.termination(self._state, reward)
        else:
            return ts.transition(self._state, reward)

# Create the environment
env = TetrisEnvironment()
tf_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(env)

# Create a Network
actor_net = CustomActorDistributionNetwork(
    tf_env.observation_spec(),
    tf_env.action_spec(),
    fc_layer_params=(100, 100, 100))

value_net = value_network.ValueNetwork(
    tf_env.observation_spec()
)

# Define the PPO Agent
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)

agent = PPOAgent(
    tf_env.time_step_spec(),
    tf_env.action_spec(),
    actor_net=actor_net,
    value_net=value_net,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter)

agent.initialize()

# Replay buffer
replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,
    batch_size=tf_env.batch_size,
    max_length=100000)

# Data collection function
def collect_step(environment, policy, buffer):
    time_step = environment.current_time_step()
    action_step = policy.action(time_step)
    next_time_step = environment.step(action_step.action)
    traj = trajectory.from_transition(time_step, action_step, next_time_step)

    # Add trajectory to the replay buffer
    buffer.add_batch(traj)

# Collect initial data
for _ in range(100):
    collect_step(tf_env, agent.collect_policy, replay_buffer)

# Dataset generates trajectories with shape [BxTx...]
dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
    num_parallel_calls=3, 
    sample_batch_size=64, 
    num_steps=2).prefetch(3)

iterator = iter(dataset)

# Training the agent
num_iterations = 20000

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    collect_step(tf_env, agent.collect_policy, replay_buffer)
    experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
    train_loss = agent.train(experience).loss

    step = agent.train_step_counter.numpy()

    if step % 100 == 0:
        print(f'step = {step}: loss = {train_loss}')

# Start the server to interact with the Lua script
def start_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=1234):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {addr}")
        handle_client(client_socket)
        client_socket.close()
def divide_list(values, divisor):
    if divisor == 0:
        raise ValueError("Division by zero is not allowed.")
    
    return [value / divisor for value in values]
def handle_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        try:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if data:
                print("Received from client:", data)
                # Convert the received data back to the environment's state
                if data:
                    data = data.split(',')
                    next_piece_id = int(data[0])
                    current_piece_id = int(data[1])
                    current_piece_x = int(data[2])
                    current_piece_y = int(data[3])
                    board = list(map(int, data[4:204]))  # Assuming board is 200 bytes long
                    score = int(data[204])
                    gameState = int(data[205])


                observation = [next_piece_id, current_piece_id, current_piece_x, current_piece_y]
                observation = observation + board
                observation = [x/255 for x in observation]

                state = np.array(observation, dtype=np.float32)

                # Update the environment's state and internal variables
                env._state = state
                env._score = score
                env._game_state = gameState

                # Create a time step from the state
                time_step = ts.restart(state)
                
                 # Get the action from the agent's policy
                action_step = agent.policy.action(time_step)
                action = action_step.action.numpy().flatten()

                action = [bool(x) for x in action]

                # Send the controller inputs back to the client
                response = json.dumps(action.tolist())
                client_socket.sendall(response.encode() + b'\n')
                print("Sent to client:", response)

            else:
                # If data is empty, client closed connection
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error receiving data: {e}")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()

And the error I am getting.
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError
Exception encountered when calling layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1280 values, but the requested shape has 640 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork):
  • observations=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 2, 204), dtype=float32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 2), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=True
  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 44, in call
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 2])
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1280 values, but the requested shape has 640 [Op:Reshape]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 44, in call
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 2])
  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 160, in <module>
    train_loss = agent.train(experience).loss
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1280 values, but the requested shape has 640 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork):
  • observations=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 2, 204), dtype=float32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 2), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=True

I recognize that the requested shape is half the size of logits so I tried to alter the tf.reshape() comand to match. I tried both of the below.
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions*2, 2])

logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 4])

Both resulted in the same result:
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError
Exception encountered when calling layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 10 values, but the requested shape has 20 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork):
  • observations=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 204), dtype=float32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=False
  In call to configurable 'PPOAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.ppo.ppo_agent.PPOAgent'>)
  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 44, in call
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 4])
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 10 values, but the requested shape has 20 [Op:Reshape]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 44, in call
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 4])
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 10 values, but the requested shape has 20 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork):
  • observations=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 204), dtype=float32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 44, in call
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_actions, 4])
  File "/home/david/Control/test6.py", line 116, in <module>
    agent = PPOAgent(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 10 values, but the requested shape has 20 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer 'CustomActorDistributionNetwork' (type CustomActorDistributionNetwork):
  • observations=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 204), dtype=float32)
  • step_type=tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  • network_state=()
  • training=False
  In call to configurable 'PPOAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.ppo.ppo_agent.PPOAgent'>)

I'll be honest I have no idea what I'm doing here, I don't know what parts of the reshape are important to my needs and as such am hesitant to mess with this too much, I just found while writing this that logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size*2, num_actions, 1]) actually works but that errored out later and I have no idea if the problem is with the arbitrary change to the shape or with another issue with my code.

Make sure that the tensor logits you are reshaping has a total of batch_size * num_actions * 2 elements. Adjust num_actions accordingly based on your specific needs and ensure consistency in the dimensions.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

How do I ensure consistancy in the dimensions? that is literally what I am asking.
